# Assetic links not working correctly in Symfony production environment

Tags: symfony

I've been working on a Symfony CRM for a while, and noticed recently that when I come across a 500 server error or a 404 page not found error, I get the page that only shows in dev, which gives you all the information. I'm not sure why I didn't realise this before as I was not using the `app_dev.php` route.

I checked my `app.php` file. There's a line as follows:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

So, just to test, I changed the value to `false`. However, in doing this all my assetic links for the css and the javascript don't work anymore and I get links such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/f024ab1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/776bfd1.css" />
```

rather than:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/f024ab1_part_1_styles_6.css" />`

which does work.

I'm not entirely sure why I'm only getting the dev environment regardless of whether or not I use `app_dev.php` so can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug` (or `bin/console` if you're on symfony3). Also: Clear your cache afterwards (`cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug`).

Comment: The 2nd parameter to `AppKernel`s constructor is wether `debug` is enabled or not. In the standard symfony installation it actually defaults to `false` in `app.php` - so you (or one of your co-workers) actually set that to `true`, for whatever reason.

Comment: Great, thanks - it was that I hadn't done the assetic dump. Yeah, not sure why it was true - I've set it back to false and it's working as expected now.